# What axioms are needed to define measures as particular kinds of pseudometrics?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

My metrics/pseudometrics take values in $[0,\infty].$

Given a measure $\mu$ on a measureable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$, we get a corresponding pseudometric $\mu$ on $\mathcal{A}$ by defining $$d(A,B) = \mu(A \Delta B),$$ where $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference of sets. Furthermore, we can recover the measure from $d$ by observing that $d(A,\emptyset) = \mu(A \Delta \emptyset) = \mu (A)$. This suggests that there should be a definition of "measure on $(X,\mathcal{A})$" in which they're characterized as pseudometrics on $\mathcal{A}$ satisfying certain axioms.

> **Question.** What axioms do we need to define measures in this way?

*Remark.* A straightforward solution is to assume that $d(A,B) = d(A\Delta B,\emptyset)$ and that $d(-,\emptyset)$ is a measure. But I'm hoping for something more interesting than this.